# IJCADのgced.dllについて

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD2018MechanicalでC#を使用してAutoCADの時のソースを移植する作業を行っております。

エンティティを選択してフィレットを行う処理があるのですが、AutoCADの時は

```
// Import部分
[DllImport("accore.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "acedCmd")]
private static extern int acedCmd(System.IntPtr vlist);


// フィレット実行部分
ResultBuffer buf = new ResultBuffer();
buf.Add(new TypedValue(5005, "_FILLET"));
buf.Add(new TypedValue(5009, pt1));
buf.Add(new TypedValue(5009, pt2));
acedCmd(buf.UnmanagedObject);
```

で動作していたのですが、IJCADに移植を行う際に

```
// Import部分
[DllImport("gced.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "gcedCmd")]
```

というふうにImport部分を変更しましたが、これで実行しようとすると
「DLL 'gced.dll' の 'gcedCmd'というエントリポイントが見つかりません。」
というエラーが発生します。

このacedCmdの代わりになるものを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import部分を次のように変更するとgcedCmdが呼び出せると思います。

```
[DllImport("gcap.dll", EntryPoint = "gcedCmd", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

また、オブジェクトIDや選択セットを渡さない場合であれば、
Editor.Command()メソッドを使用してコマンドを呼び出すこともできます。

```
var ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
ed.Command("FILLET", pt1, pt2);
```

こちらのページが参考になると思います。
https://support.ijcad.jp/hc/ja/articles/206242761